# Psql error: column "paraglider.idMaker" does not exist but it exist

Tags: javascript, postgresql

Hello i got a query that throw the this error :  error: column "paraglider.idMaker" does not exist

```
const result = await client.query('SELECT *, "maker.is" AS "maker_id", "maker.name" AS "maker_name"  FROM "paraglider" JOIN "maker" ON "paraglider.idMaker"="maker.id"');
```

There no error of typo

This work perfect in the CLI PSQL:

```
SELECT paraglider.*, 
       maker.id AS maker_id, 
       maker.name AS maker_name 
FROM paraglider 
  JOIN maker ON "idMaker"=maker.id;
```

I got this result:

```
 id |  name  |   type   | release_year |  created_at   | idMaker | maker_id | maker_name 
----+--------+----------+--------------+---------------+---------+----------+------------

  1 |Tonic 2 |    all   |         2019 | time_stamp_ex |       1 |        1 | Skywalk

  2 |Arcus RS|    all   |         2017 | time_stamp_ex |       2 |        2 | Swing
```

I don't understand why my query work in the CLI of PSQL but not in my code.
I try to change:

```
'ON "paraglider.idMaker"="maker.id"'
```

in

```
'ON "idMaker"="maker.id"'
```

and the error change in err: error: column "maker.id" does not exist.

Comment: `"maker.is" AS "maker_id"`?

Comment: `"paraglider.idMaker"` shold be `paraglider."idMaker"`

Comment: And `"maker.id"` should be `maker.id`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok i find a query who work :

`SELECT paraglider.*, maker.id AS maker_id, maker.name AS maker_name FROM paraglider JOIN maker ON "idMaker"=maker.id`

But don't understand where the problem come from...

Comment: If you don't understand what the [double quotes do](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS) then you shouldn't use them when you create the tables. Then you can completely forget about them